# Can't download in software centre

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix 'Check your Internet connection' error in software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/how-to-fix-check-your-internet-connection-error-in-software-center)

I am trying to download packages using software centre on 11.04 but i keep getting the message:

"Failed to download package files
Check internet connection"

Though my internet connection works fine on firefox.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It usually means that there is a problem with the server , not you. If the application you are downloading is from an 3rd party source, it would be worth the trouble to notify its maintainer. If it is from the official repositories you might want to try using another server. This can be done from the software center at edit --> software sources --> first tab on "download from"