# How to fix 'Check your Internet connection' error in software center?

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download package files error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/failed-to-download-package-files-error)

I have a problem with the Software Center. I am not able to install anything from it. After I entered my authorisation password it gives the following error:

```
Failed to download package files check your internet connection.
```

After that it says

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages. The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.
```

I have my internet connection, and I'm working with that.

Comment: attach the output of this command to your question: sudo apt-get update     . most likely it is an error with repositories.

Comment: See this answer:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/70553/software-center-not-downloading/70636#70636