# Ubuntu software center "Check your internet connection"

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix 'Check your Internet connection' error in software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/how-to-fix-check-your-internet-connection-error-in-software-center)

I can't install anthing from Ubuntu software center. When i want to download application, opens an error and it says "Check your internet connection". Internet connection works in browser, skype and thunderbird.