# How to overcome "check your Internet connection" installing Chromium or Google Chrome?

Tags: installation, software-center, google-chrome, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a “Failed to download package files” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error)
>   [How to fix 'Check your Internet connection' error in software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/how-to-fix-check-your-internet-connection-error-in-software-center)

I want to install Google Chrome, i.e., Chromium, on Ubuntu 11.10.

I went to the Software Center, and then tried to install Chromium.

But the error shown was check your Internet connection but the net was working fine.

Comment: Chrome is based off Chromium, if you want Chrome got to the google page, google.com/Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Then do this,

To install Google Chrome in Ubuntu , press Ctrl – Alt – T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When Terminal opens, run the commands below to add Google repository key.

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
```

When the file opens, add the below line and save it.

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

finally

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple thing. Go to https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/.
Click on download and save the file.

Open terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and just type

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

Drag and drop .deb package you downloaded and enter. Give user password and your Chrome will be installed.